# Problem when displaying articles inline block

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn HTML and CSS. However, I was doing an exercise, and now I'm stuck because those 4 articles in `<section id="news">` don't display side by side, and I wasn't able to figure out what was happening.

[image: image of the site]

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #1A4575;
}

header {
  background-color: #2F5075;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

nav {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #2B71C2;
  color: white;
}

nav>a:hover {
  color: #80B7F7;
}

header>h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

section#breaking>article {
  width: 700px;
  background-color: rgba(172, 35, 35, 0.719);
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3.5px;
}

section#news {
  background-color: #2B88C2;
}

section#news>article {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

section#news>h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

aside {
  background-color: #1A4575;
  color: white;
}

footer {
  background-color: #2F5075;
  text-align: center;
  color: #368FF5;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Menu</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">a</a>
    <a href="#">b</a>
    <a href="#">c</a>
    <a href="#">d</a>
    <a href="#">e</a>
  </nav>

</header>
<main>
  <section id="breaking">
    <article>
      <h2>Breaking news</h2>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda culpa asperiores voluptate. Eius pariatur vero, at repellendus sunt sequi ad qui doloribus excepturi provident ipsam, libero deleniti culpa nihil et.</p>
      <aside>
        <p>Written by João Marcelo</p>
      </aside>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="news">
    <h1>Daily News</h1>
    <article>
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit amet facilis officia ex eos quae possimus nisi, nostrum saepe, debitis obcaecati ea doloribus adipisci, soluta veritatis! Deserunt quam molestias ut.
      </p>
      <aside>
        <p>Written by Pedro Henrique Vasconcelos</p>
      </aside>
    </article>

    <article>
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi asperiores quo omnis fugit error ipsum provident aut libero consequatur minima illo, distinctio sed, culpa temporibus deserunt obcaecati quidem. Quia, assumenda.
      </p>
      <aside>
        <p>Written by Leonardo Alves de Paiva</p>
      </aside>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2>Title 3</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi asperiores quo omnis fugit error ipsum provident aut libero consequatur minima illo, distinctio sed, culpa temporibus deserunt obcaecati quidem. Quia, assumenda.
      </p>
      <aside>
        <p>Written by Beatriz halfd</p>
      </aside>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2>Title 4</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi asperiores quo omnis fugit error ipsum provident aut libero consequatur minima illo, distinctio sed, culpa temporibus deserunt obcaecati quidem. Quia, assumenda.
      </p>
      <aside>
        <p>Written by Joana Bohemia</p>
      </aside>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
<footer>
  <p>Developed by Leonardo</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: dont use `inline-block` use `flexbox` instead. also you should take a focus on learning the concept of `responsive web design`. Your website is unresponsive as you sue to many fixed unit siezs instead of defining them with relative units.

Comment: Oh ok! I have no idea of what flexbox is but i'm going to research about it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the vertical align to top on the articles. The default is baseline.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #1A4575;
}

header {
  background-color: #2F5075;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

nav {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #2B71C2;
  color: white;
}

nav>a:hover {
  color: #80B7F7;
}

header>h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

section#breaking>article {
  width: 700px;
  background-color: rgba(172, 35, 35, 0.719);
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3.5px;
}

section#news {
  background-color: #2B88C2;
}

section#news>article {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  vertical-align:top;
}

section#news>h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

aside {
  background-color: #1A4575;
  color: white;
}

footer {
  background-color: #2F5075;
  text-align: center;
  color: #368FF5;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Menu</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">a</a>
    <a href="#">b</a>
    <a href="#">c</a>
    <a href="#">d</a>
    <a href="#">e</a>
  </nav>

</header>
<main>
  <section id="breaking">
    <article>
      <h2>Breaking news</h2>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda culpa asperiores voluptate. Eius pariatur vero, at repellendus sunt sequi ad qui doloribus excepturi provident ipsam, libero deleniti culpa nihil et.</p>
      <aside>
        <p>Written by João Marcelo</p>
      </aside>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="news">
    <h1>Daily News</h1>
    <article>
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit amet facilis officia ex eos quae possimus nisi, nostrum saepe, debitis obcaecati ea doloribus adipisci, soluta veritatis! Deserunt quam molestias ut.
      </p>
      <aside>
        <p>Written by Pedro Henrique Vasconcelos</p>
      </aside>
    </article>

    <article>
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi asperiores quo omnis fugit error ipsum provident aut libero consequatur minima illo, distinctio sed, culpa temporibus deserunt obcaecati quidem. Quia, assumenda.
      </p>
      <aside>
        <p>Written by Leonardo Alves de Paiva</p>
      </aside>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2>Title 3</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi asperiores quo omnis fugit error ipsum provident aut libero consequatur minima illo, distinctio sed, culpa temporibus deserunt obcaecati quidem. Quia, assumenda.
      </p>
      <aside>
        <p>Written by Beatriz halfd</p>
      </aside>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2>Title 4</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi asperiores quo omnis fugit error ipsum provident aut libero consequatur minima illo, distinctio sed, culpa temporibus deserunt obcaecati quidem. Quia, assumenda.
      </p>
      <aside>
        <p>Written by Joana Bohemia</p>
      </aside>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
<footer>
  <p>Developed by Leonardo</p>
</footer>
```